# Error in an OnClickListener; can't start Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created a button and I when I tap on it, it should start the `Activity` `Wifi`.
When I test this code, nothing happens apart from this error:

```
02-19 08:34:33.455 10528-10528/test.sterela.com.sterelaapplication D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

Wifi.java (the Activity where I have the button):

```
package test.sterela.com.sterelaapplication;

/**
 * Created by DB020490 on 17/02/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Wifi extends Activity {
Intent myIntent=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_main_wifi);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BouttonWifi);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Perform action on click
            myIntent = new Intent(Wifi.this, WifiActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="test.sterela.com.sterelaapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Accueil_Parametres"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".WifiActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

content_main_wifi.xml (Wifi Activity layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/ForceSignal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWifiName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AP Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWifiMac"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="00:00:00:00:00:00" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

WifiActivity.java (the Activity I'm trying to start):

```
package test.sterela.com.sterelaapplication;

import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WifiActivity extends Activity {

    private Button boutonRechercher;
    private ListView listeViewWifi;
    private List<WifiItem> listeWifiItem;
    private WifiAdapter wifiAdapter;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private WifiBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_wifi);

    listeViewWifi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewWifi);
    boutonRechercher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRefresh);

    boutonRechercher.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(wifiManager != null)
                wifiManager.startScan();
        }
    });

    wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    listeWifiItem = new ArrayList<WifiItem>();
    wifiAdapter = new WifiAdapter(this, listeWifiItem);
    listeViewWifi.setAdapter(wifiAdapter);

    broadcastReceiver = new WifiBroadcastReceiver();

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}


public WifiManager getCurrentWifiManager() {
    return wifiManager;
}

public WifiAdapter getWifiAdapter() {
    return wifiAdapter;
}

public List<WifiItem> getListeWifiItem() {
    return listeWifiItem;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where is the @Override annotation in onClick? Just copy/paste error?

Comment: Where is the button inside your xml layout?

Comment: Can't you narrow down the cause of your problem a little in order to not have the entire code posted?

Comment: @Bertrand Da Silva you didn't mentioned wifi activity in menifest file??

Comment: So Betrand, please be more clear and bring some light into this question. 1. Is Android Studio showing some Errors? 2. Can You compile Your code? 3. where is Your Button inside the layout?

Comment: What you posted is not an error but just debug logging.

Answer (score 0):

You are using layout `R.layout.content_main_wifi` inside `Wifi` activity, but there is no button in that layout file with id `R.id.BouttonWifi`.

I am sure you are getting a `NullPointerException` while running this code.

**Solution:** Add a button to layout `R.layout.content_main_wifi` with id `R.id.BouttonWifi`.

Comment: possibly it´s just a copy paste error, AS should warn him about if there is no button and consequently no id....usually not possible to build the project...

Comment: may be button is in another layout, thats why AS not showing warning

Comment: Yes this could be a possibility. A button with that id might be in some other layout.